# Assign value to checkboxes

Tags: vba, excel

Hye there, I new with vba here.

I want to use checkboxes to link with the series collections of a chart. I put the check boxes in a sheet which contain the chart altogether. I have a lot of checkboxes here to be assigned to "true" value.

```
Private Sub Controls_Initialize()

     'Make default for checkboxes
      CheckBox1.Value = True
      CheckBox2.Value = True
      CheckBox3.Value = True
      CheckBox4.Value = True
      CheckBox5.Value = True
      CheckBox6.Value = True
      CheckBox7.Value = True
      CheckBox8.Value = True
      CheckBox9.Value = True
      CheckBox10.Value = True
      CheckBox11.Value = True
      CheckBox12.Value = True
      CheckBox13.Value = True
      CheckBox14.Value = True
      CheckBox15.Value = True
      CheckBox16.Value = True
      CheckBox17.Value = True
      CheckBox18.Value = True
      CheckBox19.Value = True
      CheckBox20.Value = True
      CheckBox21.Value = True
      CheckBox22.Value = True
      CheckBox23.Value = True
      CheckBox24.Value = True
End Sub
```

I have tried this code but can't

```
For i = 1 to 24
     Controls("CheckBox" & i).Value = True
Next i
```

The questions are
1. Is there any other code that can make it simple?
2. How to link the check boxes with the series collection in the activechart? Example, if the checkbox return value false, the series collection will be deleted/hide(perhaps?). And when it returns value true, the series collection of the same data will be added back in the chart. I would like to make the chart interactive.

If there is any reference that I can reviewed, do tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so assuming from what you've given, I'd think the problem is that the interpreter doesn't know *i* is an **integer**.
To fix this, we can implement something along the lines of `Dim i As Integer` to implement *i* as an integer.

---

We could try this:

`Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 to 24
     Controls("CheckBox" & i).Value = True
Next i`

Comment: ohh I'm sorry, I forgot to tell that I've already declare the i like you did.. but still can't, error..